# how to use multiple array in foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

1. how to use multiple array in foreach?

   correct this syntax

   ```
    $URRightsFor =   $_POST['URRightsFor'];
    $URRightsName =   $_POST['URRightsName'];
    foreach ($URRightsName,$URRightsFor as $key => $value) {
       $sql= "INSERT INTO tblUserRights (`URUserId`,`URRightsName`,`URRightsFor` )value( '$URUserId','$URRightsName[$key]','$URRightsFor[$key]')";
       $result=mysql_query($sql);
    }
    if($result) {
      echo "Thank you!";
    } 
    else {
     ECHO'ERROR';
    }
   ```

Comment: you can't use foreach on 2 non-array variables. It should give you a pretty solid error message. You shouldn't use `mysql_*` either, It's deprecated **and** you're leaving yourself wide open to injection attacks

Comment: use a for loop for that

Comment: Read the PHP manual on how to build arrays.

Comment: First of all: Try using PDO for your mysql connection. To solve your problem, write a function to loop through your arrays? When an array is found, call the same function so it loops that array as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SPL's MultipleIterator

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL | MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['URRightsFor']), 'rightsFor');
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['URRightsName'], 'rightsName'));
foreach($mi as $details) {
    echo $details['rightsFor'], ' - ', $details['rightsName'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

or if you're using a more recent version of PHP, you can use `list` in your `foreach`

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['URRightsFor']));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST['URRightsName']));
foreach($mi as list($rightsFor, $rightsName)) {
    echo $rightsFor, ' - ', $rightsName, PHP_EOL;
}
```

or you could combine your two arrays into one using:

```
$rightsArray = array_combine(
    $_POST['URRightsFor'],
    $_POST['URRightsName']
);
foreach($rightsArray as $rightsFor => $rightsName) {
    echo $rightsFor, ' - ', $rightsName, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: I think this level of sophistication might be a bit beyond the OP